# How to get all Dates given "Day Name" Between 2 Dates in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

How to get All Days between given two Dates, given "Day Name"?
Ex: **Start_Date** = **Jan 1, 2011**
      **End_Date** = **Jan 20, 2011**
      **Day Name** = **Sunday**

Here we need to get all Dates with dayname as "SUNDAY"
Ex:

```
Jan 02, 2011
Jan 09, 2011
Jan 16, 2011
```

Comment: Most likely you will find a function in Jon Skeet's [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

Answer (score 12):

I like to use `Enumerable.Range` for tasks like that:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2011,1,1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2011,1,20);

var datesThatAreSundays = Enumerable
    .Range(start.DayOfYear, end.Subtract(start).Days + 1)
    .Select(n => start.AddDays(n - start.DayOfYear))
    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: Perfect but it does not include start date how to include that ?

Comment: @DharaPPatel as it happens the code was not correct. It is fixed now to work correctly for any dates, and it includes the given start and end dates in the result. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 20);

while (startDate < endDate)
{
   if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
   {
      // Do something
   }

   startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 20);
string dayName = "sunday";

List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
for (DateTime runDate = startDate; runDate <= endDate; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
{
    if (runDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower() == dayName)
        list.Add(runDate);
}
```

or even using [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx)

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 20);
string dayName = "sunday";
DayOfWeek dow;
Enum.TryParse(dayName, true, out dow);

List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
for (DateTime runDate = startDate; runDate <= endDate; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
{
    if (runDate.DayOfWeek == dow)
        list.Add(runDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested:

```
DateTime start = x;
DateTime end = y;

while (start.DayOfWeek != z)
    start = start.AddDays(1);

while (start <= end)
{
    //DoStuff

    start = start.AddDays(7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
 var firstDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
 var lastDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 20);

 var result = (from el in Enumerable.Range(0, (lastDate - firstDate).Days)
                      let date = firstDate.AddDays(el)
                      where date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
                      select date).ToArray();
```